# Financial Modelling Prep API calls for stock_news/press_releases

Tags: python, url, python-requests

I'm trying to use FMP's stock data API to generate a general overview on stock information and data. The problem I'm encountering is for stock_news or press_releases aspect of the API I'm getting countless errors, whether it would be from null data to just overall string errors when I believe I don't have any. Below I've referenced sections of my code using this data:

```py
def get_financial_data(ticker):
    api_key = os.getenv('FINANCIAL_MODELING_PREP_API_KEY')
    base_url = "https://financialmodelingprep.com/api/v3"

    try:
        # Fetching basic financial data
        profile_url = f"{base_url}/profile/{ticker}?apikey={api_key}"
        profile_res = requests.get(profile_url)
        profile_data = profile_res.json()[0]

        # Fetching historical data (income statement, balance sheet, cash flow)
        income_stmt_url = f"{base_url}/income-statement/{ticker}?limit=5&apikey={api_key}"
        balance_sheet_url = f"{base_url}/balance-sheet-statement/{ticker}?limit=5&apikey={api_key}"
        cash_flow_url = f"{base_url}/cash-flow-statement/{ticker}?limit=5&apikey={api_key}"
        press_releases_url = f"{base_url}/press-releases/{ticker}&limit=5&apikey={api_key}"

        income_stmt_res = requests.get(income_stmt_url).json()
        balance_sheet_res = requests.get(balance_sheet_url).json()
        cash_flow_res = requests.get(cash_flow_url).json()
        press_releases_res = requests.get(press_releases_url).json()

        financial_info = {
            "latest_price": profile_data.get('price', 'N/A'),
            "market_cap": profile_data.get('mktCap', 'N/A'),
            "pe_ratio": profile_data.get('pe', 'N/A'),
            "sector": profile_data.get('sector', 'N/A'),
            "income_statement": income_stmt_res,
            "balance_sheet": balance_sheet_res,
            "cash_flow": cash_flow_res,
            "press_releases": press_releases_res
        }
        return financial_info
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred while fetching financial data for {ticker}: {e}")
        return None
```

And here I have created some more comprehensive sections on calling dictionaries:

```py
    for period in financial_data['income_statement']:
        user_message_content += f"Date: {period['date']} - Revenue: {period['revenue']}, " \
                                f"Net Income: {period['netIncome']}\n"

    for period in financial_data['balance_sheet']:
        user_message_content += f"Balance Sheet {period['date']}: Total Assets: {period['totalAssets']}, " \
                                f"Total Liabilities: {period['totalLiabilities']}. "

    for period in financial_data['cash_flow']:
        operating_cash_flow = period.get('operatingCashFlow', 'N/A')
        investing_cash_flow = period.get('investingCashFlow', 'N/A')
        user_message_content += f"Cash Flow {period['date']}: " \
                                f"Operating Cash Flow: {operating_cash_flow}, " \
                                f"Investing Cash Flow: {investing_cash_flow}. "

    user_message_content += "\n--- Latest Stock News ---\n"
    for news_item in financial_data['press_releases']:
        user_message_content += f"Date: {news_item['date']} - Title: {news_item['title']}\n" \
                                f"Summary: {news_item['text']}\n\n"
```

Below I've provided my most recent error:

```
{'Error Message': 'Invalid API KEY. Please retry or visit our documentation to create one FREE https://financialmodelingprep.com/developer/docs'}
<class 'str'>

<... rest of error ...>

    user_message_content += f"Date: {news_item['date']} - Title: {news_item['title']}\n" \
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I only get the API not available error only when using press_releases, so I know it's not a problem in regards to my API key. My question is whether I'm using this dictionary wrong, or it's just a matter of me having the basic subscription, and me needing to upgrade to a better plan.